# Need to prove $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\;dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1}\theta\;d\theta$

Tags: calculus

Please help me. I'm having trouble trying to prove 
$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\;dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1}\theta\;d\theta$

Comment: Do you know the trigonometric substitutions to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\sin(u)\;$ using substitution you get the following:
$$dx=\cos(u)du$$
$$\int_0^1{\frac{x^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx}=\int_{\sin^{-1}(0)}^{\sin^{-1}(1)}{\frac{\sin^{2n+1}(u)}{\cos(u)}\cos(u)du}=\int_{\sin^{-1}(0)}^{\sin^{-1}(1)}{\sin^{2n+1}(u)du}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}{\sin^{2n+1}(u)du}$$

Comment: The limits of integration should be changed to $sin^{-1}(1)$ and $sin^{-1}(0)$ in the second integral not the third.